# Modifying a controller response with annotation-based AOP?

Tags: spring, grails, groovy, aop, spring-aop

I'm trying to add headers to a controller response via AOP, and I'm not sure how to get access to the controller or the controller's response.

How do I do this?

This is my current annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target([ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.FIELD])
public @interface NoCaching {
}
```

And here is my current aspect:

```
@Aspect
@Component("noCachingAspect")
class NoCachingAspect {

    @Pointcut("@annotation(com.grailsrocks.cacheheaders.NoCaching)")
    public void nameDoesntMatter() {
    }

    @Before("com.grailsrocks.cacheheaders.NoCachingAspect.nameDoesntMatter()")
    public void beforeMethod(JoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        println 'hellowoeijf'
    }
}
```

And here's how I use the annotation:

```
@NoCaching
    def annotations(){
        println 'bar'
    }
```

How can I get access to the controller targeted by the annotation so as to modify the response object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a blog post about this a while back, see http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=80